# how to change CRUD "add" button name?

Tags: atk4

by default the CRUD **add** button name is the same as model name. how can we change that?

```
$tabs->addTab('Users')->add('CRUD')->setModel('Admin_User');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### If you can - first set the model caption properly

Set $model->`$caption` of your model.

### If it's just the CRUD which needs to have custom button name, then

Set $crud->entity_name either by extending or by specifying second parameter to add('CRUD')

### Finally if you want to change it after crud->setModel()

You can access button through $crud->add_button, and use either set() or setLabel().

Comment: in the third way, when I click the btn it shows this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\test\page\admin.php on line 20

Comment: `$crud->add_button->set('Text to be shown at Add button');` and `setLabel()` don't work for me too

Comment: `$crud->add_button->set()` must be added after `$crud->setModel()`
It works!

Answer (score 2):

```
$tab = $tabs->addTab('Users');
$crud = $tab->add('CRUD');
$crud->setModel('Admin_User');
$crud->entity_name = 'Text to be shown at Add button';
```

Or

```
$tab = $tabs->addTab('Users');
$crud = $tab->add('CRUD');
$crud->setModel('Admin_User');
$crud->add_button->set('Text to be shown at Add button');
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\test\page\admin.php on line 20

Comment: probably you use not latest version of atk4
https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/View/CRUD.php#L99

Comment: how can I understand which version I'm using? (I searched the CRUD.php file and there was the "public $add_button;" in that so I think it's ok.

Comment: if version is ok that means you are doing something wrong before this line )))

Comment: You can find it in atk4/VERSION file

Answer (score 2):

OR

```
$this->add('CRUD',array('entity_name' => 'Text to be shown at Add button'));
```

Comment: It worked! but it add "Add" at the begining of the string automatically! for wxample if you give it "test" it shows "Add test"!!!

Comment: In that case you probably have to define you own add button.